# Comparison of two constants of a general form

Tags: functions, derivatives, number-comparison

In a lecture, our sir gave us a question comparing 2 constant values that were all of the form ​​​​​​​​$α^β$ and $β^α$. Example ($π^e$, $e^π$) and ($2008^{2009}$, $2009^{2008}$). He used variable assumptions:

$α^{1/α}$ = $a^{1/ab}$ and $β^{1/β}$ = $b^{1/ab}$

After this, I formed the function *f(x) = $x^{1/x}$* and checked it’s  monotonicity but I can’t reach any result. Is that the correct method? And is there any better/other method to compare such values i.e. values of the form ​​​​​​​​$α^β$ and $β^α$? If yes, please explain.

Comment: $a^b \ge b^a \iff \frac{\ln a}{a} \ge \frac{\ln b}{b} $. So, generally the graph of $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is considered.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn’t think that way. But I still have a doubt. The graph of lnx/x is monotonic on both sides of x = e. So if a and b lie on either side of x = e, then is it possible to compare manually? If yes, then how?

Comment: That’s a good point. In fact, I don’t think anything can be said about that case.

Comment: I don’t think so either. Anyways, thanks for the help.